# Notice: Undefined variable: current abc.php on LineA

Tags: php, foreach, isset

I have a php code as shown below in which I am getting the error `Undefined variable: current abc.php at LineA`.

```
if (isset($helloWorld[$this->index])) {
    $current = $helloWorld[$this->index];
}

if (isset($current)) {
    if (!is_array($current)) {
        return $list;
    }
}
foreach ($current as $key => $values) {                     // LineA
    $attName = $helloChamp[$key];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $valName = $helloHow[$key][$value];
        $list[$attName][] = $valName;
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried so that I can fix the problem of undefined variable at `LineA` above. I have added `foreach` loop inside the `if block` at `LineZ`. Let me know if its the right
away to fix the Undefined variable problem for this particular case.

```
if (isset($helloWorld[$this->index])) {
    $current = $helloWorld[$this->index];
}

if (isset($current)) {
    if (!is_array($current)) {
        return $list;
    }
}
if (isset($current)) {                                           // Line Z
    foreach ($current as $key => $values) {                     // LineA
        $attName = $helloChamp[$key];

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $valName = $helloHow[$key][$value];
            $list[$attName][] = $valName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing `$current` before the `if` statement ?

Like this:

```
$current = []; // Initialize $current here before you use it anywere...
if (isset($helloWorld[$this->index])) {
    $current = $helloWorld[$this->index];
}
```

Then you can remove the `if` statements, since the `$current` variable would always be an array. So, It would be like this:

```
$current = [];
$list = [];

if (isset($helloWorld[$this->index])) {
    $current = $helloWorld[$this->index];
}

foreach ($current as $key => $values) {
    $attName = $helloChamp[$key];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $valName = $helloHow[$key][$value];
           $list[$attName][] = $valName;
    }
}
```